# Oblique projection onto orthogonal complement

Tags: geometry, orthogonality, projection-matrices

I'm looking for an expression for the oblique projection of the row space of a matrix $A$ along the row space of the matrix $B$ onto the orthogonal complement of $C$. Simply modifying the well-known oblique projection formula for the oblique projection of A along $B$ onto $C$

$A/_BC=[A/B^\perp][C/B^\perp]^\dagger C$ (or other/similar expressions)

turns out to be not that easy...

The notation $A/B$ means the orthogonal projection of $A$ onto $B$ and can be written as

$A/B = AB^\top(B B^\top)^\dagger B = A\Pi_B$.

with $\Pi_B$ as the projection matrix. $A/B^\perp$ means the orthogonal projection onto the orthogonal complement of $B$ and can be expressed as

$A/B^\perp = A(I-\Pi_B)$

with $I$ as an appropriate identity matrix. The superscript $\dagger$ means the Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse. The upper expression $A/_BC$ can also be written as

$$A/_BC=A \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      C&B
    \end{array}
\right] 
\left[\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
      CC^\top&CB^\top\\
      BC^\top&BB^\top
    \end{array}
\right]^{-1}\right]_{first~r~columns} C $$

with r the row dimension of $C$. What I'm looking for is a expression for $A/_BC^\top$.

Does someone have at least an idea how I could find such an expression?

Comment: You are using a lot of non-trivial notation, and explaining it might make your question accessible to a wider audience. I'm also uncertain whether projective-geometry and projective-space are really appropriate tags: doing a projection and doing projective geometry are two different things, and you seem to be doing the former exclusively.

Comment: I'm sorry. This notation is quite common in the books and papers I use, thus i thought it is quite common in general.
I added further explanation in my first post.